# Why is a numpy-generated list of 0.0s throwing <RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars>, rather than a divide by 0 error?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

When I have a list of randomly generated numpy numbers and they end up as 0.0, I get an invalid value warning and a nan result rather than a simple divide by 0 exception.

I can add in a check for 'nan' earlier and return 1 instead (commented in the numsim function) and simply hope I'm not hiding problems in my actual data.  When I print out the lists that generate nan, the values show up as 0.0. I've read the documentation (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.seterr.html) and googled / looked in SOF and it seems most common to get this with too large of numbers or too small of numbers that get rounded to 0.  So I thought if I was getting too tiny a number it would have printed that number rather than 0.0 --- even more, I would have guessed numpy wouldn't generate a random number that was so tiny.

My questions then are -- Why does this happen, since the numbers appear to be 0.0?  Is there anything better I can do beyond acting like it doesn't matter, catching nans, and returning 1?  Most importantly, can I be sure that an actual list of 0.0's will perform correctly?  (in the code below, list2 won't throw the error, but list1 will if you run it a few times).

Simplified code (run this several times until numpy generates a list of 0.0's for you):

```
import math
import numpy as np

list1 = list(np.random.rand(10) * np.random.randint(2))
list2 = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]

def numsim(x, y):
    try:
        num = 1 - (abs(x - y) / (abs(x) + abs(y)))
    except:
        num = 1
    ## add this to catch NaN earlier
    #if math.isnan(num):
    #    print("Caught it.")
    #    num = 1
    return num

def mean_sim(tlist1, tlist2):

    summation = sum([numsim(i1, i2) for i1, i2 in zip(tlist1, tlist2)])
    num = 1/len(tlist1) * summation 

    if math.isnan(num) or math.isnan(summation):
        print('Summation: %s' %str(summation))
        print('Num: %s' %str(num))
        print('tlist1:')
        print(tlist1)
        print('tlist2:')
        print(tlist2)
        exit() # instead, probably will: num = 0 # instead of NaN

    return num

print("Running with numpy built lists...")
mean_sim(list1, list1)
print("Running with list of 0.0...")
mean_sim(list2, list2)
```

The output (on successful crashing):

```
$ python3 ./test2.py 
Running with numpy built lists...
./test2.py:9: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
  num = 1 - (abs(x - y) / (abs(x) + abs(y)))
Summation: nan
Num: nan
tlist1:
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
tlist2:
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's begin with noting that in

```
np.random.rand(10) * np.random.randint(2)
```

the factor `np.random.randint(2)` is either 0 or 1 with equal probability. And you get the whole array multiplied by it, so with probability 50% the array is all zeros. Is this not what you expected?

If you wanted to have either 1 or 2, that would be `np.random.randint(1, 3)` per [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.randint.html).

---

Your code looks strange because you are using Python lists, and `zip` etc instead of built-in vector operations in NumPy. Here is my version:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.random.rand(10) * np.random.randint(1, 3)
b = np.random.rand(10) * np.random.randint(1, 3)
arr_diff = np.abs(a-b) / (np.abs(a) + np.abs(b))
num = np.sum(1 - np.nan_to_num(arr_diff))
print(num)
```

Notice that `nan_to_num` is called to replace by `nan` values, resulting from both numbers being 0, by 0. (Which makes sense since these should get similarity 1).

---

NumPy division is different from plain Python division. Whereas 0/0 raises an exception in Python, executing `np.array([0])/np.array([0])` returns `array([ nan])` with merely a warning:

```
__main__:1: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in true_divide
```

This behavior can be changed using [`seterr`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.seterr.html):

```
np.seterr(divide="raise", invalid="raise")
```

ensures that an error is thrown for both 1/0 and 0/0 kinds of errors.

Comment: Yes, it's written above entirely for the purpose of generating an array of 0's quickly.  My original code needs a list of length 7, where each list is an array of random ints between 0 and 6, and I'd get the NaN problem infrequently.  I converted my other functions similarly and I think converting my actual data to numpy arrays and performing math thusly will work out. Thanks.